# Application crash at customer machine

Tags: c++, crash, windbg

Our DCOM server crashes at customer machine. The application does not crash if I enable Page Heap,Put pdb files or attach AD Plus. It does not crash in any of our machines.

I generated crash dump with NTSD using Just In Time feature of Windows in the customer machine. But the crash location is different at different times.

What technique should I use to identify the cause of the crash?

Comment: Perhaps you could try making the question less terse. I'm sure you know "Put pdb files" means, but it is certainly not in my lingo

Comment: Do you mean that debug builds work? Perhaps it is related to optimization, #ifdef _DEBUG code etc

Comment: @Sehe: We took the release build. The pdb files are related to release build

Comment: can you post a few example stacks? does it crash in functions dealing with memory/heap?

Comment: You wouldn't be the first to solve undiagnosable heap corruption problems by leaving the debugging tool permanently in place.  If you can't diagnose it from the minidump and can't get a failure with debugging tools in place then there's little left beyond a thorough code review.

Comment: The fact that application stops crashing when you turn on page heap could suggest that there is a racing condition in your application. Threre are few things you can do: a) verify heap integrity in the dumps you collected; b) check all data structures in your dumps where race condition could occur -- a corrupted structure woud give you a clue on which part of the code is involved. If you have free threaded DCOM server you might not realize you have multi-threaded application. If this is the case, you can try changing that to appartment threaded .

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a memory corruption. Generally the stack trace is not reliable at this point. First thing to do is to look at the stack segment. Best way to do this is to dump the raw stack and not a stack trace and see if the stack can be manually reconstructed. In addition when the memory gets overwritten check if you see a data pattern in the overwritten data.